# Does spring dependency injection create singleton objects?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

How does spring manage these objects internally?

When are the singleton objects created and destroyed?

Comment: An almost identical question was asked recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599068/can-the-object-created-in-ioc-container-be-called-singleton-if-not-why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, Spring beans are basically singletons.  Spring will create a single instance of each of your classes, and it will generally do this when Spring is initialized.

However, this is nearly infinitely customizable.  Spring can also create a new instance of a bean whenever you ask for that bean by name, or it can create beans for the length of a request, or it can use a singleton but not instantiate it until the first time you invoke it, or several other things.

The discussion of when beans are instantiated and how long they last is a discussion of a bean's "Scope".  Check it out in the documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes

Comment: thanks , It means i have defined same bean with two different name in spring the IOC container creates two objects which have the spring singleton scope....???

Comment: yes, although I suppose the terminology would be that you have defined two different beans of the same class.