# Thread safety in Spring Boot with Instance variables

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

Are methods (without using class variables)  thread safe when using Spring Boot ?
I came across carious links where they mentioned instance variables aren't safe always ?

My doubt is how can I create a race condition ? Is the below code thread safe ?And if yes then how can i make it thread - unsafe without using class variables

```
 @RestController
        public class GreetingController {
        
            @Autowired
            private GreetingService greetingService;
        
            @GetMapping("/hello")
            public void greeting(@RequestBody MyUser myUser) throws Exception  {
                greetingService.getData(myUser);
             }  

 @Service
    public class GreetingService {
        
        @Autowired
        private DBService dBService;
        
        public void getData (MyUser m ) throws InterruptedException
        {
            
            dBService.getData(m);
        }




@Repository
         public class DBService {
    
        
           public MyUser getData(MyUser myUser) throws InterruptedException {
            
            System.out.println( "message  before: "  + myUser.getA() + " Thread : " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
    
            
            Thread.sleep(18000);
            System.out.println( "message after "  + myUser.getA() + " Thread : " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
            
            return myUser;
            
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In resume: yes, apparently, this code is thread-safe. Since you're using Servlets, each request will be served in a different thread provided by the servlet container (if you're using the default configurations for Spring Boot, the servlet container is a Embedded Tomcat).

Why apparently? Because this code is only thread-safe if the instances of objects declared in the class scope are also thread-safe (i.e `GreetingService` must be thread-safe)

Take your own example:

The `Thread#sleep` executed in a first request has no effect on the subsequent ones (i.e other request will **not** be blocked) because the subsequent ones are served on different threads, as said above.

You will be fine as long as you don't assign new values to the global variables during a request life cycle.

Comment: @Matheus.Thanks for the explanation. So unless I am using class variables and changing its state .i am fine.That's what i understood.

Comment: Correct. Do not manage state on Singleton beans that are shared between multiple threads, especially in a web environment. That may cause problems and then becomes thread-unsafe

Comment: Just last doubt .If I wanted to share states between different threads what's the recommended way?esp in Spring

Comment: I think ensuring that only one thread at a time is allowed to change the object (by using the `synchronized` keyword) is a fine way to go. I've never had to share state between threads, so maybe i'm not the best person to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

By default (see [Does spring dependency injection create singleton objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615168/does-spring-dependency-injection-create-singleton-objects)), objects injected by spring dependency injection (@Autowired in your case) are singletons.

In your example, there will be exactly one instance each of the controller, service, and repository. So, not inherently thread-safe.

The usual pattern for these classes is as you have shown - use class-level variables only for instances of objects that are themselves thread-safe.

Do not keep any state in class-level variables unless you want that data shared (which is rare), and your code will be thread-safe.

If you do share state on purpose, make sure that you take care to make access to that state thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks.But is my code above thread safe ?If not how?

Comment: All of it looks threadsafe to me except for maybe your DBService, which I'm guessing is not your real code anyway. If that were a "normal" database service that used a JDBC connection pool to access a database and return a result (without mutating any instance variables), then that would definitely be threadsafe too.